# Best way to use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock when moving data around

Tags: ios, parse-platform, nsnotificationcenter

I have a Tableview that gets data with findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock in viewDidLoad and passes that data to a Detail View Controller no problem.

Im having trouble managing the flow of findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock. Here is a example: I have a like button on the detail view and when pressed it increments the UILabel and displays it. It also then gets the object in Parse then increments and saves it... Everything good.

```
 @IBAction func likeButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("likeButtonPressed()")
    // Adding the like to label
    mixLike!++
    var stringForCount: String = String(mixLike!)
    mixLikeLabel.text = stringForCount
    // Saving the like back to Parse
    var query = PFQuery(className: "musicMixes")
    query.whereKey("info", equalTo: mixNameLabel.text)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects {
                //var votes = object["votes"] as! Int
                let mixObject:PFObject = object as! PFObject
                mixObject.incrementKey("votes", byAmount: 1)
                mixObject.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil, selector: nil)
              print("mixObjectSaved")
            }

        } else {
            print("Error getLikeCount()")
        }
        print("sending Notification...")
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reload", object: nil)
        print("sent Notification...")

    }

} // likeButtonPressed End
```

I also then call a NSNotification back to the Table View so the Table View can update the likes to match the users like click on the detail view (See bellow)
The NSNotification calls this function in the Table View, which removes the like array, grabs the new likes again and then reloads the Table View.

```
@ objc func reloadTableData(notification: NSNotification){
    print("Notification Recived, Removing Likes and Reloading. reloadTableData()...")
    self.mixLikeArray.removeAll()
    //self.stringForCountArray.removeAll()
    print("Like array Data removed, getting data again...")
    var query = PFQuery(className: "musicMixes")
    query.orderByAscending("date")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            for object in objects {
                let mixLike = object["votes"] as! Int
                self.mixLikeArray.append(mixLike)
                print("New mixLikeArray data is \(self.mixLikeArray)")

            }
        } else {
            print("error getting like object")
        }
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        self.allTableView.reloadData()
    });

}
```

I see three issues wrong with how this works at the moment. likeButtonPressed() Is sometimes sending the NSNotification before mixObject.saveInBackgroundWithTarget is finished. Meaning that the incremented like won't be displayed on the table view.

Secondly if I was to click like then click back to tableview swiftly the app will crash. This is because I'm guessing both likeButtonPressed() and the NSNotification function still has not been completed.

Also in @ objc func reloadTableData(notification: NSNotification) once again the

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.allTableView.reloadData()
});
```

Is being called before the findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock is being completed? Anyway round this?

How would you suggest I can remodel this to work efficiently? Im pretty new to coding and a bit rusty with designing the best ways to do things... I know the concept behind completion handlers could I use these? I know that Parse likes to work in the background though hhhmmmm.....

Answer (score 0):

to fix your reloadTableData problem, you should trigger the reload once the parse block is done executing, which means moving this line

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.allTableView.reloadData()
});
```

inside the block

```
 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!,error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        for object in objects {
            let mixLike = object["votes"] as! Int
            self.mixLikeArray.append(mixLike)
            print("New mixLikeArray data is \(self.mixLikeArray)")

        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            self.allTableView.reloadData()
        });
    } else {
        print("error getting like object")
    }
}
```

That will ensure that it gets triggered once parse is done updating objects.  Currently its triggering before that while the block is executing.  It also means that it won't reload if you get an error as you probably need to handle that differently anyway.

As for your problem of the notification happening before the saving is complete, you are calling . saveInBackgroundWithTarget but don't seem to send anything into it.  You could use `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` and then use `dispatch_group` `dispatch_group_enter`, `dispatch_group_leave`, and `dispatch_group_notify` inside the block to make your program wait till everything is done being saved before sending the notification.

So you would create a dispatch_group

```
 dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
```

And then call it dispatch_group_enter in the for loop through the objects

```
 for object in objects {
     dispatch_group_enter(group);
     let mixObject:PFObject = object as! PFObject
     .....
 }
```

Then call dispatch_group_leave on the mixObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock

and wrap the notification in dispatch_group_notify

```
  dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 4
      NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reload", object: nil)
});
```

Something like that

It sounds more daunting than it is, here's a [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/63338/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-2) tutorial to bring you up to speed on how to use it, if your not familiar

Comment: Thanks for the info!! Adding reloadData to the block dose work. But when using the parse block for in on a loop it reloads the data after every append.  I wanted to see if there was a way to avoid this and only append at the end of the iteration.

Im going to look into that article It seems like GCD is the solution for this. More importantly how do I stop the app from crashing if I go back to the table view before the object is saved and the notification is completed. There must be a way to remodel my code to avoid this

Comment: @user4671001 sorry I will admit i'm not familiar with how parse works so not sure i can help you there.  If the problem is that your trying to reload before the updating is done, then dispatch_group and dispatch_group_notify will definitely be helpful for you